# Birthday poem python programme

Tags: python

Q:

> Write a program called birthday_021.py that reads lines of text. where each line consists of a person’s date of birth. A date of
> birth is specified by three integers: a day, a month and a year. The
> program should determine on which day of the week each person was born
> and print the corresponding line from the poem:
>
> Monday’s child is fair of face Tuesday’s child is full of grace

> Wednesday’s child is full of woe Thursday’s child has far to go

> Friday’s child is loving and giving Saturday’s child works hard for a

> living Sunday’s child is fair and wise and good in every way For

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime 
import calendar 
  
def findDay(date): 
    born = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d %m %Y').weekday() 
    return (calendar.day_name[born]) 

date = '26 11 2001'
print("You were born on a " + findDay(date))
```

My problem:

In the code I posted above it prints "you were born a Friday".

The problem is I Don't know how
to add the poem line for Friday to the output. My answer should be "you were born on a Friday and Friday's child is loving and giving"

Comment: Have you tried using `dictionary` with key as weekday?

Comment: Create a dictionary that would have keys `"Monday"`, `"Tuesday"`, etc and values - the corresponding poem lines. Then add to print `your_dicitonary[findDay(date)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary where the day of the week is the key, and the value is the line of the poem to print.

```
import datetime
import calendar


def findDay(date):
    born = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d %m %Y').weekday()
    return (calendar.day_name[born])


lines = {"Monday": "Monday’s child is fair of face",
         "Tuesday": "Tuesday’s child is full of grace",
         # Fill in the rest of the rows...
         }


date = '20 11 2001'
print(lines[findDay(date)])
```

Or, if you want to print the sentence with the day as well

```
day = findDay(date)
print("You were born on a " + day + ". " + lines[day])
```

Comment: but how can I print "you were born (day) + poem line. All in one line e.g "you were born a Monday and Monday's child is fair of face"